# Javax Validation - Disabling annotation logging for invalid values

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-annotations, javax.validation

I have put a constraint on a field like so:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

@Pattern(regexp=SOME_REGEX)
private String someField;
```

The regex is working correctly, but in the case of an invalid value, the value is getting logged:

```
[Field error in object 'containingSomeField' on field 'someField': rejected value [InvalidValue123];
```

Is there a way to disable this logging in annotations? I have not been able to find anything thus far.

I do not want to disable logging in general, just the printing of this value.  Masking the value would suffice.

EDIT:

Found the answer to my own question. You can override the default exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResponseExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
 
  @Override
  public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
      MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
      @NonNull HttpHeaders headers,
      @NonNull HttpStatus status,
      @NonNull WebRequest request
  ) {
    // Your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can configured specific log level for javax.validation through property log4j.logger.org.hibernate.validator ([How to turn of hibernate-validator DEBUG logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348118/how-to-turn-of-hibernate-validator-debug-logger)). For dev env you can set debug level and for prod - error.

Comment: Specifically mentioned that I did not want to disable logging in anyway.